# block inside NSOPeration subclass crashing in the device but not in the simulator

Tags: automatic-ref-counting, objective-c-blocks, nsoperation

I have been struggling with this piece of code for a while and I just don't know why it happens that when running in the device ... the app crashes with an **EXC_BAD_ACCESS Error** but when running in the simulator it runs fine.

The scenario: A subclass of NSOperation that makes an async connection with NSURLConnection and gets custom data. When finished, it calls the block with the downloaded data.

### Here is the .h file:

```
@interface FileDownloader : NSOperation <NSURLConnectionDataDelegate>

typedef void (^CompletionBlockForFile)(NSData *);

- (id)initWithCompletionBlock:(CompletionBlockForFile)block;

@end
```

### and the .m file:

```
@interface FileDownloader ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) CompletionBlockForFile completionBlock;

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableData *downloadedData;

- (void)downloadFileWithCompletionBlock:(CompletionBlockForFile)block;

@end


@implementation FileDownloader

@synthesize downloadedData = _downloadedData;
@synthesize completionBlock = _completionBlock;

- (id)initWithCompletionBlock:(CompletionBlockForFile)block
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _completionBlock = block;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)main
{
    if (self.isCancelled) return;
    if (_completionBlock) {
        [self downloadFileWithCompletionBlock:_completionBlock];
    }
}

- (void)downloadFileWithCompletionBlock:(CompletionBlockForFile)block
{   
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        NSURLConnection *connection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
        [connection start];
    });
}

... delegate methods of NSURLConnection

@end
```

And Finally, the method that adds the operation object to the queue at the MainViewController Class:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
    FileDownloader *fileDownloader = [[FileDownloader alloc] initWithCompletionBlock:^(NSData *data){      // <----- HERE IS THE EXC_BAD_ACCES ERROR JUST WHEN RUNNING IN THE DEVICE !!! :S
        NSLog(@"%@", data);
    }];

    [queue addOperation:fileDownloader];
}
```

Can anybody explain me what am I doing wrong? And is it correct to put strong for the block var in the property? Why not assign? Or weak ?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blocks should be copied and not retained.
Change

```
@property (**strong**, nonatomic) CompletionBlockForFile completionBlock;
```

to

```
@property (**copy**, nonatomic) CompletionBlockForFile completionBlock;
```

and it should work

Comment: OK, thanks for the answer, I changed what you said but it stills doesn't work. Then, after just thinking a little bit more I realized that my block var **CompletionBlockForFile** was named **competionBlock** and since this is an NSOperation Subclass, there is an already var named equal. So, I made the change to the name of my var in the class and.... it works then.

Comment: Thank you very very much for the **strong** instead of **copy** I know why now. Thanks a lot.